# Is it possible to insert text in a existing .otp file through Python?

Tags: python, libreoffice

I'm looking for a way/module to insert a string of text formatted by position and text size, into an already existing .otp file(OpenDocument Presentation Template/Libre&OpenOffice version of a .ppt file). Preferably through Python. I've tried googling but the only thing I find is about macros and I'm not sure if that will work the way I want it to.

As an example I'm looking for an end product like this, where the text is inserted through running a Python script.

[image]

I imagine the outline of the script to look something like:

```
import modules
file = 'cat.otp'
open file
some function for inserting formatted text(right size, text size etc) in otp file
```

Comment: It could be done with python-uno. This requires LibreOffice to be started with a command line script. But it sounds like you are looking for a solution that does not involve LibreOffice. In that case, unzip the file and make changes, which shouldn't be too difficult with python. You could also try searching for "python open document presentation format", which shows for example https://pypi.org/project/odpslides/.

Answer (score 0):

you wrote `.opt` in text and in pseudo-code `.otp`, but extension should be `.odp` for a presentation file. `otp` is for a master. If you just want to add content this should work for both:

While there is a convenient lib for pptx: `python-pptx` I don't know one for OpenOffice-Files.

If you don't have to create from scratch but just edit something (and it sounds like that) you may unpack the file via [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html), edit the `content.xml` and zip back the whole file structure to odp-file. If you take your demo-file and read the xml (use notepad++ with XML-Tools extension and pretty print function to de-linearize) it is quite self-explaining, you'll get an idea pretty fast.